How to get data with Simple HTML DOM Parser?
<div class="siteList"><a href="https://test1.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><div class="badge" style="background:transparent; position:absolute;"><img src="/img/ran.png" width="30" height="30"></div><li class="siteLogo"><img src="/data1_250x70.png" alt width="250" height="auto" title></li><li class="siteInfo"><h3 style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;">TestSite 1</h3></li></a></div>

<div class="siteList"><a href="https://test2.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><div class="badge" style="background:transparent; position:absolute;"><img src="/img/ran.png" width="30" height="30"></div><li class="siteLogo"><img src="/data2_250x70.png" alt width="250" height="auto" title></li><li class="siteInfo"><h3 style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;">TestSite 2</h3></li></a></div>

<div class="siteList"><a href="https://test3.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><div class="badge" style="background:transparent; position:absolute;"><img src="/img/ran.png" width="30" height="30"></div><li class="siteLogo"><img src="/data3_250x70.png" alt width="250" height="auto" title></li><li class="siteInfo"><h3 style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;">TestSite 3</h3></li></a></div>

I want to get data Array a tag href, in li siteLogo img SRC, h3 plaintext
    $R = array();
    foreach($html->find('div.siteList') as $element) {
        array_push($R,[$element->href,$element->plaintext,$element->src]);
    }

This is my code but no have SRC..
i want insert data Array to SQL
$R = array();
foreach($html->find('div.siteList') as $element) {
    array_push($R,[$element->href,$element->plaintext,$element->src]);
}


You are iterating over div.siteList, but those elements do not have a href or a src property. If you want to access properties of children/descendants even further down, then you need to access those elements first.

@CBroe i need 2 foreach?

No, probably not. Once you are "at" some node, you can call find on it again, to select descendants.

@CBroe foreach($html->find('div.siteList')->find('li.siteLogo img') as $element) { is right?

No, you need to keep on looping over those divs, and then inside the loop, select descendants for each individual one. $element->find(...)
